# Updating status bar while reading large Excel file leads to high memory consumption

Tags: c#

I read large Excel file with `OpenXML` and see no significant problems. Everything is just ok, no matter how large is the file. But the problem is, I want to show in the status bar a kind of log information about processed rows. I do it like this:

```
private void setStatus(string txt)
{
    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = txt;
    statusStrip1.Refresh();
}
...
int count = 0;
// rows iteration
count++;
setStatus(count + " rows processed")
...
```

If I comment out this code, then my program cosumes about 30MB, if not it starts to consume about 470MB. My question is how to optimize this operation, in terms of memory cunsumption. Or, if it is even possible when the processed file and, thus, the number of ticks is too large.

Comment: You should start by running your program with a memory profile, and understand what happens and why. Also your code example doesnt really help

Comment: I guess, it is not clear where setStatus is called. It is called inside a loop where I process each row. So, there is one call per each row. And in my test file there are 700K rows.

Comment: Do you really need to update the status on every row of a 700k row file?

Comment: Try amending your code to only call SetStatus on every 1%o f the input data rather than on every row.

Comment: I would also be looking for a memory leak somewhere beneath the SetStatus call. A memory profile should help in tracking that down. Are you running *FxCop* on your code until it passes clean?

Comment: @ Nick Bailey. Now, I'm not sure. I just wanted to make it more transparent, so that a user could see the progress of processing. @Pieter Geerkens. I will try it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I never dealt with memory profiling in c# and do not even know what is FxCop. The problem is I'm new to c#. I think, I should dive deep into all this memory stuff.